# sphinx Autodoc using a function from module which has been mocked

Tags: python, mocking, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have recently started using sphinx autodoc for documentation.

I had an import

```
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SelectField, BooleanField
```

in the project so I ended up mocking wtforms

But in the same file I had a class which used IntegerField in a class variable as follows

```
class DbEditableForm(Form):
    data_version = IntegerField('data_version', validators=[Required()], widget=HiddenInput())
```

On using autodoc in a file which importes DbEditableForm

I got the follow error

```
/home/ninad/third_year/balrog/docs/source/admin_api.rst:5: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class u'SingleRuleView' from module u'auslib.admin.views.rules'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 519, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/ninad/third_year/balrog/auslib/admin/views/rules.py", line 12, in <module>
    from auslib.admin.views.forms import EditRuleForm, RuleForm, DbEditableForm, \
  File "/home/ninad/third_year/balrog/auslib/admin/views/forms.py", line 138, in <module>
    class DbEditableForm(Form):
  File "/home/ninad/third_year/balrog/auslib/admin/views/forms.py", line 142, in DbEditableForm
    data_version = IntegerField('data_version', validators=[Required()], widget=HiddenInput())
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Any Idea how to use autodoc for the file importing DbEditableForm ?